# How to find collision distance or impact time

Tags: forces, material-science, collision, free-fall

I wanted to calculate the impact force of some falling object

Let's assume this object has:

- $85kg$ mass
- the cross-section area: $0.75m^2$ (if that's necessary)
- Speed of **$42.64m/s$** when it reaches the impact point

With this, what would be the impact force when it falls to a concrete road

1. My first approach: 
   I've calculated the kinetic energy to be $1,812.2J$, but to get the impact force from that I'd need a **collision distance**, which I'm not sure how to get
2. My second approach: 
   I've calculated the impulse ($Ft$) to be $3,624.4Ns$, but again I'd need the **impact duration** to get the actual impact force

I realize that without one of those variables, I can't calculate the impact force, but how could I calculate either the collision distance or the impact force here? What variables would I need? (I assume something like the hardness of the concrete, but I'm not sure what to do with that)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are right, you need the impact duration or collision distance. In order to obtain that you need information about the elastic properties of both, target and impactor. With the information you presented, you cannot solve for either.

Making things simple, you can assume a perfectly rigid target and an elastic impactor. Then you can equate the kinetic energy to the elastic energy and derive a time or distance from that. The simplest assumption you can make is that [Hook's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hooke%27s_law) and [Hertz contact theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contact_mechanics) applies and you have a uniformely elastic body. For instance, [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/physics/0402036) analyses it for elastic spheres

In practise it is very hard to get theory and experiment to confirm well as small irregularities in the surface and alignment can make a huge difference. Additionally temporal and spatial resolution needed to analyse collision time and distance in detail are challenging - distance is easier - yet even there you have a rebound-effect even for perfectly inelastic collisions.